# Secure php API with API-Key set as session variable?

Tags: php, api, security

Let's say i've index.php and login.php, where login.php only acts as API, called via AJAX on the login form located in index.php

As i do it via AJAX, i cannot only allow localhost. What i've done now is setting a API-Key Session variable in index.php and check it in login.php.

index.php:

```
session.start()
$_SESSION['MYKEY'] = 'ABCDEFG'
```

login.php:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['MYKEY']) || $_SESSION['MYKEY'] !== 'ABCDEFG') {
    http_response_code(401); // UNAUTHORIZED
    echo "UNAUTHORIZED!";
    die();
}
// more code for actual login logic
```

Would this be a good security measure or is this aboslute non-sense?

If not, what i could/should do instead, but with keeping it "dynamic" via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most widely used methods to secure a PHP site against CSRF

---

> for more details CSRF token https://www.getastra.com/blog/php-security/php-csrf-protection/

use this code for your index.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    function genrateString($len = 15) {
        $string = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $stringLength = strlen($string);
        $key = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $key .= $string[rand(0, $stringLength - 1)];
        }
        return $key;
    }
    
    $_SESSION['token'] = genrateString(15);
    
?>
```

HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];?>">

<!-- use jquery or javascript to get value for token & send to the backend through ajax -->
```

and add this code for your login.php page to validate the token

```
$token = $_POST['token'];

$ses_token = $_SESSION['token'];

if($ses_token == $token){ //this is only true for a valid token
    
    $return = ['message' => 'valid token',  'status' => true];
    
} else {
    $return = ['message' => 'invalid token',  'status' => false];
    
}
```